# Extract data from multiple tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql

My problem: I have a few tables in mysql database with column "URL". I want to extract all of URLs to text file or another table. 
Is it good way to go?

```
DELIMITER $$    
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE link()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE tablename varchar(1000) DEFAULT "";

    DECLARE link_tables 
        CURSOR for
            SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name like '__baza%' and COLUMN_NAME like 'url';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

    OPEN link_tables;

    getTable: LOOP
        fetch link_tables into tablename;
        IF finished = 1 THEN s
            LEAVE getTable;
        END IF;
        select url from tablename into ... <<<< is it good idea? what to do next?
    END LOOP getTable;
    close link_tables;

END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL link();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE link_urls (prefix VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( 'SELECT url FROM ', table_name) SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
        INTO @sql
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name like CONCAT(prefix, '%');
    SET @sql = CONCAT( 'CREATE TABLE urls ', @sql );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d155e8d83307860db740595c28c07961)

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know that It can be done in such easy way.